# Ant build.xml not reading env properties

Tags: java, ant

I have a cmd script file, which sets all the environment values and invoke ant class to build the java project.

I have:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

set in build.xml and

```
<property name="CD" value="${env.CDTEC}"/>.
```

build.xml unable to read these env values set from the cmd script file. If I echo the values from command prompt that prints, but not from the ant.xml file. Getting the error as

```
BUILD FAILED
c:\Users\test\Projects\Spring testing\build.xml:85: c:\Users\test\Projects\Spring testing\${env.CDTEC}\lib does not exist.
```

I added echo message in build.xml 
as

```
<echo message="Message from ${this.CDTEC} Client" />
```

and printing that as

```
'Message from {env.CDTEC} Client'.
```

Command prompt is printing these values but Ant is not able to access these env values, any idea why?

Comment: Without at least part of your build.xml we can only guess.  In general you will need to follow [the ant property docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

Comment: Is the issue resolved? can you show your build.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Is the environment variable set externally to ANT?

## Example

Setting the variable and calling ANT

```
$ CDTEC=hello ant
Buildfile: /....../build.xml

build:
     [echo] CDTEC=hello
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <property environment="env"/>

  <target name="build">
    <echo message="CDTEC=${env.CDTEC}"/>
  </target> 

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes this is exactly what I am doing. Setting a variable externally from the cmd file and calling ant from the same cmd file, but echo tag throws error as  BUILD FAILED
c:\Users\test\Projects\Spring testing\build.xml:85: c:\Users\test\Projects\Spring testing\${env.CDTEC}\lib does not exist.

Comment: @MHAR Sounds like you have two problems. Firstly clearly the variable is not being set as you expect (the command output suggest the env variable is NOT being set) and secondly line 85 of your build is doing something related to a directory. Why use environment variables? It's a very platform specific way to pass information to ANT. Why not use the -D option instead to set a property within ANT? Alternative options are property files.

Comment: Thanks again. yes the issues is that env variable set in the command prompt is not being read by the ant script? do you know why this is happening?.. if I can resolve that , whole problem is solved.  This same script is running in another system without any error. I am trying to set up the build script on another system and getting into this problem

Comment: I am passing arguments with -D option and that works , Thanks Mark